# How to query WorkflowOutboundMessage?

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

I need to query existing Workflow Outbound Messages in my system - by URL which it contains. And then get workflow which it relates to.

Tried to play with Metadata API, but all I managed to get - list of all that items and they did not contain URL - that was listMetadata query.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unfortunately. Only the Tooling API supports such a query, and the metadata for the object is all contained in a field called "metadata." When you include this field, which has a JSON output, you can only return one at a time. In other words, there's no direct way to query the data. Your best option is to export all of the workflow rules and use a search tool like `grep` or a Find in Files feature available in most operating systems and IDEs.

Comment: Should I use something like "describe" from metadata endpoint to export all that workflow rules? Or it's also a task for Tooling API?

Comment: @sleepwalker Yes, you can do a wildcard workflow retrieve, `<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>43.0</version>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
</Package>` and from there use something like `grep -re "url-to-find"`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine, however does not return workflows for custom objects. What's the way to get for custom objects as well?

Comment: @sleepwalker Should work for custom objects, too.

Comment: unfortunately it does not. In my case it returned 54 files. Includes needed data for Account for example, but not for any custom object.

Comment: @sleepwalker only objects that have something to return will return a workflow object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81637/discussion-between-sleepwalker-and-sfdcfox).